# Inside a gradle plugin, how can I check if gradle was run with --dry-run?

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle plugin and need to find out if Gradle was invoked with -m or --dry-run, to skip certain parts in the execution of the plugin. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
println gradle.startParameter.dryRun
```

Which is:

```
println project.getGradle().getStartParameter().isDryRun()
```